# Experts problem with one perfect expert

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, online-algorithms

This question concerns a variant of the 'experts' problem and the [randomized weighted majority algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_weighted_majority_algorithm) that can be used to solve it.

This is the description of the problem from Wikipedia:

> Imagine that every morning before the stock market opens, we get a prediction from each of our "experts" about whether the stock market will go up or down. Our goal is to somehow combine this set of predictions into a single prediction that we then use to make a buy or sell decision for the day.

Let's say there are $n$ experts. If at least one of the experts is always correct, we can adopt a deterministic procedure that makes at most $\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$ incorrect stock predictions: On each day, we ask each expert to give their advice. Then we go with the majority advice. At the end of each day, we eliminate all of the experts who were wrong.

If we ever make an incorrect prediction, it must have been because at least half of the experts made the incorrect prediction. Hence, every time we make a mistake we can eliminate at least half of the remaining experts. Therefore, after making at most $\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$ mistakes we will know who the perfect expert is.

However, it appears from [these lecture notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos511/scribe_notes/0326.pdf) (middle of page 3) that there is a **randomized algorithm that in expectation makes at most $\log_2(n)/2$ errors in the worst case, when there exists a perfect expert.**

How do they achieve $\log_2(n)/2$ in expectation?

Comment: @Dmitry The wording was unclear, sorry about that. I've updated the question and hopefully it explains things better!

Comment: See Problem 3 in the relevant homework: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr08/cos511/assignments/hw5.pdf

Comment: As an aside, the lecture notes mention that this is worked out in homework. Homework is available at the very same site. You don't need us to locate the exercise.